# Customize button clear in Orbeon

Tags: forms, orbeon

Is it possible to customize 'clear' button in form runner? I want to keep some default values in form (after user clics on this button), and I want to 'clear' button leave those values and doesn't clear them.

Now I want to add refresh button or add refresh action to clear button. In my properties I have line:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*"
    value="refresh pdf save-draft review workflow-send"/>
```

But unfortunately in form runner I don't see refresh button

Answer (score 0):

If you add 'fr:buttons' tag into your form, you're able to add your own buttons. This tag should be placed in '`<fr:view>`' just after the '`</fr:body>`'. If you have configured the property `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*` to define the buttons that you want to show, it will override it. You have to explicitly place the buttons that you want to show, e.g. `<fr:save-button/>`.

I've created a quick example to show it. The following fr:buttons would show a custom clean button together with Orbeon's 'Save' and 'PDF' buttons:

```
        <fr:buttons xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                    xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                    xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
            <fr:button> 
                <xf:label ref="'Clear'"/><!--You can change it to a localized path-->

                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
              <!--Clean fields, but keep values for lastname and phone fields-->
                <xf:setvalue xxf:iterate="instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/*[name()!='lastname' and name()!='phone']"/>
                </xf:action>
            </fr:button> 
            <fr:pdf-button/> <!--Orbeon PDF button-->
            <fr:save-button/> <!--Orbeon save button-->

        </fr:buttons>
```

You can see another example about custom buttons in the following link: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/form-builder-wizard

Comment: Than You for response. Actually I want to reach following goal: I want to have button that refresh page. Is it possible in form runner? I read there: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes that I can add refresh page but it doesn't work for me. Regards

Comment: I have never needed the 'Refresh' button, but Orbeon has it. What do you mean by it does not work? Please specify better your problem and the expected behaviour.

Comment: Yep, it does not seem to show it by just adding the property, the only way it's shown is by adding it explicitly   into fr:buttons. Probably a bug, I don't know I never needed the refresh button.  @ebruchez or avernet should know why it's not shown by property configuration. You could add into fr:buttons while waiting their answer.